# How do I compile ClojureScript from Clojure?

Tags: clojure, compilation, lisp, google-closure-compiler, clojurescript

So I'm getting an error when I try to compile clojurescript:

```
WARNING: Required namespace not provided for cljs.core
Mar 19, 2015 11:48:23 PM com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /Users/charles/Develop/clojure/hummingcat/out/hummingcat/core.js:3: ERROR - required "cljs.core" namespace never provided
goog.require('cljs.core');
^

Mar 19, 2015 11:48:23 PM com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager printSummary
WARNING: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
ERROR: JSC_MISSING_PROVIDE_ERROR. required "cljs.core" namespace never provided at /Users/charles/Develop/clojure/hummingcat/out/hummingcat/core.js line 3 : 0
```

I'm doing everything by the book, so far as I can tell. For some reason, it doesn't have access to the clojurescript core library. Here's the clojure that's calling it:

```
(cljs.closure/build input_path {:output-to output_path :optimizations :advanced})
```

And here's what I'm trying to compile:

```
(ns hummingcat.core)

(enable-console-print!)
(println "HELLO!!!!")
```

The thing is, it is compiling the clojurescript (althought not to the `output_path`). Here's what it produces:

```
// Compiled by ClojureScript 0.0-3058 {}
goog.provide('hummingcat.core');
goog.require('cljs.core');
(hummingcat.core.enable_console_print_BANG_.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$0 ? hummingcat.core.enable_console_print_BANG_.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$0() : hummingcat.core.enable_console_print_BANG_.call(null));
var G__9815_9816 = "HELLO!!!!";
(hummingcat.core.println.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$1 ? hummingcat.core.println.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$1(G__9815_9816) : hummingcat.core.println.call(null,G__9815_9816));
```

I have not tried running this clojurescript. Any suggestions?

Comment: Rules for namespace,it may help you :http://swannodette.github.io/2015/02/23/hello-google-closure-modules/

Comment: Does this explain why the clojurescript doesn't have access to `cljs.core`?

Comment: Did you read the new [Quick Guide](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start)? If you start with the provided jar and Java 8 you'll have cljs.core.

Comment: I have read that guide. It turns out the problem is that I had vim open while trying to compile... The .swp set it off.